# How to update database with an ActionLink in a List Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an ActionLink (for update) in a list (strongly type List for display list db) page. Now I'm using the ActionLink update, change the other family of database to a string.

```
    public bool Update()
    {
        User old_user = db.Users.Where(p => p.Family == "Jacki").Single();
        old_user.Family = "Anderson";
        return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges()); 
    }

    public ActionResult changeFamily(User Us)
    {
        blUs.Update(Us);
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

Comment: An action link is for making a GET and a method that updates the database needs to be a post. Use a form and submit the form

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen said, ActionLink just works with GET request. You are updating the your database context. So either remove ActionLink and use Form or Hook the ActionLink click event in jQuery and call the submit() method.